# Replace the occurrence of a character in string skipping first occurence

Tags: python, string, duplicates

Replace the occurrence of `&` with space () except the first occurrence

```
a = "abc&def&hij&klm"
output = abc&def hij klm"
```

remove `&` comes more than one time and place a space there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple approach:

```
output = '&'.join(s.replace('&', ' ') for s in a.split('&', 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string slising:

```
ind = a.index('&')
a = a[:ind+1] + a[ind+1:].replace('&', ' ')
```

1. Find first occurance
2. Slise sting on that index + 1
3. Replace in second part all entries of char

Answer (score 0):

```
a="abc&def&hij&klm"

# split based on & character
res = a.split('&', 1)

# replace & with space in 2nd element  
res[1] = res[1].replace('&', ' ')

# now join list into string
print '&'.join(res)
```

Comment: `'&'.join` probably

Answer (score 0):

Using only `replace`

```
a = 'abc&def&hij&klm'
a = a.replace('&', ' ').replace(' ', '&', 1)
print(a)
```

Output

```
abc&def hij klm
```